# Basic database connection and deployment

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, ssms

I've created a database on .\SQLEXPRESS in SSMS.

How do I connect to the database in Visual Studio 2010? I know this is potentially a big question but my main concern is with how I'd construct the connection string. I'd right click in solution explorer and add the database file myself but I can't seem to find where the file is!?

Also, this project is to give to someone else upon completion; if I were to connect to this database how would I deploy it so that the recipient could also run it locally?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe. Maybe I'm THE C# guru incognito, using an absolute newbie identity as a disguise. Just maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside "Server Explorer"  connect to the server. Use "Add Connection" with  "Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)" option give the server name and select the database to connect.

If you are using integrated security your connection string will look like this

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;Integrated Security=True
```

or if you are using user name and password it will be

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=YourDataBaseName;User ID=UserID;Password=Password
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot Amar. From this then can I create an entity model??

Comment: Yes. Read more about How to Use Entity Model [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738677.aspx)

Comment: Looks like you are new to SO. If you are satisfied with any of the answer, you need to accept it, please go through the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 2):

```
"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MyDatabase; Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a LOT Mitch!! So how would I ensure the person I am sending this to can run the project when the 'Northwind' database may not be currently on their .\SQLEXPRESS server??

Comment: Ok. Last question - again, a potentially big one - but I'm about to look into using an ADO .net entity model so that I can handle the data I recieve from any stored procedures, for example, with custom classes - is this still possible without adding the database file to the project? Can this still be achieved just from using the connection string?

Answer (score 0):

See the link.http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk9yw1t.aspx

Comment: Welcome D:).If links help you its make me glad.